# static counters as dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a requirement of maintaining number of object/instances of a class type, treating Base and its subclasses separately.

I have Base class and **n** subclasses of Base class

I am trying to implement a static var counter as dictionary in my base class.

I am trying to implement base class, like this and I struck at declaring class variable of struct static dictionary getter & setter

```
class BaseClass {
    struct objCounter {
        static var counter = [String:Int]()
        subscript(type: String) -> Int? {
            get { return objCounter.counter[type] }
            set(value) { objCounter.counter[type] = value }
        }
    }

    class var typecounter: [String:Int] {
        ?? // 
    }
}
```

Or is there any better way to do this

**Update**
I am trying something like this, which works for base class, now I am trying to modify this to work for subclasses, any ideas?

```
class var typecounter:Int? {
    get {
        return objCounter.counter["base"]
    }
    set {
        if let value = objCounter.counter["base"] {
            objCounter.counter["base"] = value + newValue!
        } else {
            objCounter.counter["base"] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The final version, I am trying to implement is

```
class BaseClass {
    struct objCounter {
        static var counter:[String:Int] = [String:Int]()
        subscript(type: String) -> Int? {
            get {
                return objCounter.counter[type]
            }
            set(value) {
                objCounter.counter[type] = value
            }
        }
    }

    class var typecounter:Int? {
        get {
            return objCounter.counter[self.getType()]
        }
        set {

            if let value = objCounter.counter[self.getType()] {
                objCounter.counter[self.getType()] = value + newValue!
            } else {
                objCounter.counter[self.getType()] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    class func getType() -> String {
        return "Base"
    }

}

class SubClass:BaseClass {

    override class func getType() -> String {
        return "SubClass"
    }
}
```

It seems the above is working as expected!!

I will update once I have implemented and test this in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final working version that I have implemented in my project is as Below,

```
class BaseClass {
    struct objCounter {
        static var counter:[String:Int] = [String:Int]()
        subscript(type: String) -> Int? {
            get {
                return objCounter.counter[type]
            }
            set(value) {
                objCounter.counter[type] = value
            }
        }
    }

    class var typeCounter:Int? {
        get {
            return objCounter.counter[self.getType()]
        }
        set {

            if let value = objCounter.counter[self.getType()] {
                objCounter.counter[self.getType()] = value + newValue!
            } else {
                objCounter.counter[self.getType()] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    class func getType() -> String {
        return "Base"
    }

    func getType() -> String {
        return "Base"
    }

    init() {
        switch self.getType() {
        case BaseClass.getType():
            BaseClass.typeCounter = 1
        case SubClass.getType():
            SubClass.typeCounter = 1
        default: break
        }
    }

    deinit {
        switch self.getType() {
        case BaseClass.getType():
            BaseClass.typeCounter = -1
        case SubClass.getType():
            SubClass.typeCounter = -1
        default: break
        }
    }

}

class SubClass:BaseClass {

    override class func getType() -> String {
        return "SubClass"
    }

    override func getType() -> String {
        return "SubClass"
    }
}
```

If any one have better solutions, let us know, thanks